# Java "Unexpected return value" for int when returning an int

Tags: java, class, return

I have this class being executed in another file and java is telling me

```
"Unexpected return value",
```

I've searched and searched and can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm a massive Java Noob so any help will be appreciated.

```
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;

public class PopUpBox {

    public static void display(String title, String message) {
        Stage window = new Stage();
        TextField textField = new TextField();

        //Block events to other windows
        window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        window.setTitle(title);
        window.setMinWidth(250);

        //Make a label that closes the window
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText(message);
        Button closeButton = new Button("Done");
        closeButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                    Integer test = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                    //return test;
                    System.out.println(test.getClass());
                    window.close();
                }
            );

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(textField, closeButton);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        //Display window and wait for it to be closed before returning
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.showAndWait();
    }

}
```

Comment: `ActionHandler#handle` is a void method, you can't return a value from this method (this is one of the reasons I don't like lambda expressions, they hide these important details from inexperienced developers)

Comment: From where you are getting "Unexpected return value". Please share the stacktrace if you are getting an Exception or share any logs that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation of methods you're using:

[ButtonBase.setOnAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-) has a single parameter of type EventHandler. (Button inherits setOnAction from ButtonBase).

[EventHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) is an interface with a single method `void handle(T event)`
This is what your lambda expression is implementing. This is a void method so you cannot return a value of int from it.